# macOS forcefully cancel a stuck app update

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore

macOS 12.3.1, updating Xcode (v13.3 to v13.3.1) is ongoing ridiculously long considering it's a minor update and has a massive CPU usage causing a noticeable effect.

Surprisingly, the usual routine of signing out of iCloud and rebooting turned out to be useless as the process was starting up automatically.
Force quitting installId and appstoreagent did do the job of stopping the update which allowed me to launch Xcode. I don't mind skipping that update but I'd love to know if there's a way to stop Xcode from prompting update suggestions.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. After more than a week Xcode is still not updated on a macOS 12.3.1 . It just restarted downloading. It seems like Xcode 13.3.1 doesn't work on macOS 12.3.1 . Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @SnelsNick I did manage to cancel the updating process by signing out of iCloud and force quitting the two (‘InstallId’ and ‘appstoreagent’) processes so I can do my work instead of waiting on the update to finish. I’m very careful to blame this version of Xcode, just because other apps update perfectly. I’ll just wait for the next update for it.

Comment: Thank you. Yesterday I (or my Mac) managed to finally install Xcode. I signed in to my App Store account. Open App Store application, click on your name in the left bottom corner, then click on Account Settings. I was asked for my login details. I then left App Store open, opened Console and searched for "App store", that way you can track the installation progress. What also seemed to work was to download the latest Xcode version from https://xcodereleases.com/ and install that. I got installed (very quickly), but I ended up with 2 Xcode installations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a real way to disable auto updates for Xcode, but in case you are stuck in a update again, you can use `Activity Monitor` to force quit the updates and or apps.

You can always take a look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672177/xcode-installation-how-to-prevent-automatic-upgrade-of-xcode

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation going to Xcode 14.0.1.

After waiting for what I deemed to have been long enough (about a movie's worth), I started killing "installd" instances on the command line. Being nice about it wasn't enough, so I -9'd them (sudo kill -9 [pid here]).

After the third or fourth instance the spinner turned into a download progress indicator. Download was normal, and while the install completed on its own, it took a longer time than usual (about 15 minutes).

My plan B had been to use the cached Xcode pkg that is helpfully mentioned in the /var/log/install.log and perform a manual install. But it didn't get that far.